# Determining VPS requirements for a website

Tags: web-hosting, php, mysql, vps

I am on the lookout for another webhosting provider but I'm unsure what to really look for. My current hosting package is as follows:

- VMware vCloud Premier VM
- 10GB storage
- 3GB vRAM
- 2 vCPU's
- Snapshotbackups with GFS principle
- Currently debian, so I will prefer debian in new package as well

I am unsure what I need to look for in a new hosting package, since I have no idea what equals "2 virtual cpu's".
I know I need at least 200GB of traffic and preferrably 2 IP addresses.

What kind of packages would be suitable for these requirements?
Or what do I need to find out more at my current hosting?

Comment: Our [generic answer to hosting questions](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements) probably won't be of much help because this is a technical question. You might find you're better of asking this on server fault.